# Creating Complications for Apple watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication, swift3

I know how to create the basic watch complications.

I want to create complication like native Battery one (Circular Ring).

How can I fetch live data for the complications, maybe API call, or data from iPhone?

Can I create more then one same complication type?

Comment: My watch app has two complications on the same face (see my video of it at https://vimeo.com/315500076

Comment: @JamesBush My question is can I create for same type? eg: Modular small can I create multiple for Modular small for same app.

Comment: What's a complication "type"? There are Watch faces, there are complication families, and then there are complication templates. There's no type. Use the correct terminology if you want to be clear. By the way, you asked this 11 months ago; have you made a complication yet? If so, what type?

Comment: @JamesBush Check here https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/app-architecture/complications/

Comment: Yes I have created couple of complications. Sorry for confusion I meant to make multiple for same family.

Comment: Multiple what? Templates? That's what my video shows you. Why don't you just tell us what you want specifically? Tell us what the data that you want to display and where you want to display it. You shouldn't ask people to read documentation to provide you with an answer you should be able to get for yourself. What SPECIFICALLY are you wanting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to create complication like native Battery one (Circular Ring).

How can I fetch live data for the complications, maybe API call, or data from iPhone? -

> - Use WatchKit.framework to do this and use WCSession class to
>     perform the session talking between the phone and the watch.
> - You could also use the background tasks API introuduced in WatchOS 3
>     to make API calls in the background -
>     https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInwatchOS/Articles/watchOS3.html
> - To update complications in watch OS 3 - https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkapplicationrefreshbackgroundtask

Can I create more then one same complication type?

> No you cannot, one app can have only one type of complication.